# Not able upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade

I run apt `autoremove` `apt upgrade` `apt upgrade` and get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

then run `do-release-upgrade` and get

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,341 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,343 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

a look in main log says this:

```
2021-02-05 11:19:03,793 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.bionic']'
2021-02-05 11:19:03,793 INFO uname information: 'Linux chas-pc 4.15.0-135-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:38:24 UTC 2021 x86_64'
2021-02-05 11:19:04,128 INFO apt version: '1.6.12ubuntu0.2'
2021-02-05 11:19:04,129 INFO python version: '3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0]'
2021-02-05 11:19:04,131 INFO release-upgrader version '20.04.29' started
2021-02-05 11:19:04,140 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2021-02-05 11:19:04,182 INFO screen could not be run
2021-02-05 11:19:04,211 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2021-02-05 11:19:04,252 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2021-02-05 11:19:04,284 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2021-02-05 11:19:08,353 DEBUG lsb-release: 'bionic'
2021-02-05 11:19:08,353 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2021-02-05 11:19:08,354 DEBUG openCache()
2021-02-05 11:19:08,354 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2021-02-05 11:19:08,354 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2021-02-05 11:19:09,476 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-134 with 
2021-02-05 11:19:09,476 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-135 with 4.15.0-134
2021-02-05 11:19:09,830 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 101938
2021-02-05 11:19:09,830 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2021-02-05 11:19:09,831 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2021-02-05 11:19:09,832 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2021-02-05 11:19:10,951 DEBUG openCache()
2021-02-05 11:19:12,112 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-134 with 
2021-02-05 11:19:12,112 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-135 with 4.15.0-134
2021-02-05 11:19:12,471 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 101938
2021-02-05 11:19:12,471 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2021-02-05 11:19:12,472 DEBUG quirks: running focalPostInitialUpdate
2021-02-05 11:19:12,472 DEBUG running Quirks.focalPostInitialUpdate
2021-02-05 11:21:13,735 DEBUG abort called
2021-02-05 11:21:13,735 DEBUG openCache()
2021-02-05 11:21:14,862 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-134 with 
2021-02-05 11:21:14,863 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-135 with 4.15.0-134
2021-02-05 11:21:15,215 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 101938
```

Is obvious a problem here but I don't know it. What is it anyone?

Here is output of `survice snapd status` (output repeated many times untill I do control-c):

```
● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-02-05 11:00:37 CST; 22h ago
  Process: 1414 ExecStart=/usr/lib/snapd/snapd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1414 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 05 11:00:37 chas-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, s
Feb 05 11:00:37 chas-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restar
Feb 05 11:00:37 chas-pc systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Feb 05 11:00:37 chas-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start request repeated too qu
Feb 05 11:00:37 chas-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code
Feb 05 11:00:37 chas-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Feb 05 11:00:37 chas-pc systemd[1]: snapd.service: Triggering OnFailure= depende
lines 1-13/13 (END)
```

Comment: maybe relevant https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1849669

Comment: I study that but dont kno if relevent or not. I try many things but everything ends up restoring original system state and Aborting.

Comment: @cedwin I assume [nobody's findings](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2236746) are applicable in your case, what is the output of `service snapd status`?

Comment: @Kulfy please see output of `service snapd status` added above.

Comment: Easiest way is to purge snapd.

Comment: Big JOY. Purge snapd worked, upgraded Ubuntu 20.04.2. Thank you all who help.

Comment: @nobody Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The secret to my being able to upgrade to 20.04.02 was the removal (purge) of snapd. My procedure was:

1. Did a backup of the system and all files.
2. In terminal mode:
   `$ sudo apt-get purge snapd`
   Type y and Enter to continue when asked. This removed snapd from my system.
3. Clean up any remaining dependencies with `$ sudo apt-get autoremove` (type y and Return when asked if want to continue)
4. Then proceed to upgrade Ubuntu by going to "Show Applications" to bring up "Software Updater," click on "Upgrade..." and the upgrade completed without problem. (See the transcripts above for how snapd was identified as the source of the upgrading problem.)

Comment: This seems to also help from 16.04 in the windows linux subsystem.

Comment: Seems to be right from 20.04 to 22.04 also

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing snapd but it still doesn't work. Then I exited my `screen` session and run it in a normal console, then it worked.